# I am trying to sent data from my child component to the parent component using react using props, but I receive an error message

Tags: reactjs

The error message is **TypeError: this.props.updateValue is not a function** when I am in the child page.
I am trying to send data when I click on return to homepage button, from child to parent. Basically trying to set the placeholder value of my select option in the homepage to the value from the client page(child page).

**Parent code (App.js)**

```
updateState (data) {
    this.setState({newValue: data});
}
render(){
    <Select options={dashboardsMonthAndYear} onChange={this.handleChangeDashboard}  placeholder={<clientDetails updateValue={this.updateState.bind(this)}/>} className="selectMonthYear"/>
}
```

**Child code(clientDetails.js)**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
}

updateValue(data){
    this.props.updateValue(data);
}
componentWillMount(){
    const {dashboardMonthYear} = this.props.location.state;
    this.setState({

        dashboardMonthYear: dashboardMonthYear,

    })
    this.updateValue(this.state.dashboardMonthYear);

}
```